# jQuery code not working for each iteration inside php

Tags: php, jquery

I have been adding the code to show the phone number and hide the text "Show Phone Number" once the user clicks on "Show Phone Number " text.

But this is happening only for a single iteration,for example I have two users working in say "Delhi",the Jquery part is working only for the 1st user and not for the 2nd user.

PFA the jQuery code -

```
<script>
                $("#hiddenphone").hide();//hide the initial phone number

                $("#showphone").on("click", function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        // if .hiddenphone class for this template instance is hidden
                        if ($(this).find('#hiddenphone').is(':hidden')) {
                            // change text
                            $(this).find('#hiddenphone').show();
                            $(this).find('#clickshow').hide()
                        }
                    });       
        </script>
```

PHP code -

```
            <?php
            
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = "db_name";
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
            echo '<div id="boxes">';  
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['lsearch'])) {

                $term = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_REQUEST['lsearch']);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `therapists` AS `T` inner join `personal details` as `P` ON `T`.`Therapist ID` = `P`.`Therapist ID` WHERE `Location` LIKE '%".$term."%'";
                //echo "<b> <center>Database Output</center> </b> <br> <br>";

                if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
                
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $field1name = $row["Therapist ID"];
                        $field2name = $row["Name"];
                        $field3name = $row["Designation"];
                        $field4name = $row["Identifies As"];
                        $field5name = $row["Client Group"];
                        $field6name = $row["Languages"];
                        $field7name = $row["Issues Related"];
                        $field8name = $row["Location"];
                        $field9name = $row["Phone Number"];
                        $field10name = $row["Intro"];
                        $field11name = $row["Instagram Link"];
                        $field12name = $row["Linkedin Link"];
                        $field13name = $row["Aasha URL"];
    
                  
                                echo '<div id="square-box">
                                        <div id="intro"><p>';echo $field2name;echo'</p><p>';echo $field3name;echo'</p><p>';echo $field10name;echo'</p><p>';echo $field8name;echo'</p><p></div>
                                        <div id="links"><p>';echo $field13name;echo $field12name;echo $field11name;echo'</p><p id="showphone"><span id="clickshow" style="display: inline;"><b>Show Phone Number</b></span>
                                        <span id="hiddenphone" style="display: none;">
                                                    <span>';echo $field9name;echo'</span>
                                                    
                                        </span></p></div>
                                    </div>';//;echo $field9name;echo
                        //}           
                    }
                
                    /*freeresultset*/
                    $result->free();
                    }
                }
              echo '</div>';    
            ?>
```

Comment: Element IDs must be unique by definition. You need to change to using classes instead

Comment: Well you're using html IDs which must be unique - that's what it means to be an ID. But your loop will produce multiple html elements with the same ID. Clearly that breaks the uniqueness rule. jQuery will only select the first one because it expects there will only be one element with a specific ID. The rest are ignored. If you want a selector which can bind to multiple similar elements, use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "db_name";
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
        echo '<div id="boxes">';  
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['lsearch'])) {

            $term = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_REQUEST['lsearch']);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `therapists` AS `T` inner join `personal details` as `P` ON `T`.`Therapist ID` = `P`.`Therapist ID` WHERE `Location` LIKE '%".$term."%'";
            //echo "<b> <center>Database Output</center> </b> <br> <br>";

            if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $field1name = $row["Therapist ID"];
                    $field2name = $row["Name"];
                    $field3name = $row["Designation"];
                    $field4name = $row["Identifies As"];
                    $field5name = $row["Client Group"];
                    $field6name = $row["Languages"];
                    $field7name = $row["Issues Related"];
                    $field8name = $row["Location"];
                    $field9name = $row["Phone Number"];
                    $field10name = $row["Intro"];
                    $field11name = $row["Instagram Link"];
                    $field12name = $row["Linkedin Link"];
                    $field13name = $row["Aasha URL"];

              
                            echo '<div id="square-box">
                                    <div id="intro"><p>';echo $field2name;echo'</p><p>';echo $field3name;echo'</p><p>';echo $field10name;echo'</p><p>';echo $field8name;echo'</p></div>
                                    <div id="links"><p>';echo $field13name;echo $field12name;echo $field11name;echo'</p><p id="showphone-<?=$field1name?>" onclick="showPhone(<?=$field1name?>)"><span id="clickshow" style="display: inline;"><b>Show Phone Number</b></span></p>
                                    <span class="hiddenphone" id="hiddenphone-<?=$field1name?>" style="display: none;">
                                                <span>';echo $field9name;echo'</span>
                                                
                                    </span></div>
                                </div>';//;echo $field9name;echo
                    //}           
                }
            
                /*freeresultset*/
                $result->free();
                }
            }
          echo '</div>';    
        ?>
```

$(".hiddenphone").hide();//hide the initial phone number
    function showPhone(id)

```js
    $("#hiddenphone").hide();//hide the initial phone number
    function showPhone(id)
    {
        console.log(id);
        $("#showphone-"+id).hide();
        $("#hiddenphone-"+id).css("display","block");

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="square-box">
                                
        <div id="intro">
            <p>Abhishek</p>
            <p>SSE</p>
            <p>I am abhishek</p>
            <p>Etawah</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="links">
            <p>URL here</p>
            <p id="showphone-1" onclick="showPhone(1)">
            <span id="clickshow" style="display: inline;">
            <b>Show Phone Number</b>
            </span>
            </p>
            <span id="hiddenphone-1" style="display: none;">
                <span>0000000000</span>
                                                
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="square-box">
                                
        <div id="intro">
            <p>Abhishek</p>
            <p>SSE</p>
            <p>I am abhishek</p>
            <p>Etawah</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="links">
            <p>URL here</p>
            <p id="showphone-2" onclick="showPhone(2)">
            <span id="clickshow" style="display: inline;">
            <b>Show Phone Number</b>
            </span>
            </p>
            <span id="hiddenphone-2" style="display: none;">
                <span>0000000000</span>
                                                
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="square-box">
                                
        <div id="intro">
            <p>Abhishek</p>
            <p>SSE</p>
            <p>I am abhishek</p>
            <p>Etawah</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="links">
            <p>URL here</p>
            <p id="showphone-3" onclick="showPhone(3)">
            <span id="clickshow" style="display: inline;">
            <b>Show Phone Number</b>
            </span>
            </p>
            <span id="hiddenphone-3" style="display: none;">
                <span>0000000000</span>
                                                
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="square-box">
                                
        <div id="intro">
            <p>Abhishek</p>
            <p>SSE</p>
            <p>I am abhishek</p>
            <p>Etawah</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="links">
            <p>URL here</p>
            <p id="showphone-4" onclick="showPhone(4)">
            <span id="clickshow" style="display: inline;">
            <b>Show Phone Number</b>
            </span>
            </p>
            <span id="hiddenphone-4" style="display: none;">
                <span>0000000000</span>
                                                
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

{
        alert(id);
        $("#showphone-"+id).hide();
        $("#hiddenphone-"+id).css("display","block");

    }